# How to convert a txt file into a dictionary and manage user logins in Python?

Tags: python, replit

I am working on a beginner project where I need to build a login system for one admin and multiple employees. The functionalities include:

Employees can view their salary.
The admin can change employee salaries.
The data for employees is stored in a txt file with fields such as username and salary. I am trying to achieve the following:

Convert the txt file into a dictionary for easy manipulation by the admin.
Transition from the login screen to the appropriate menu (admin or employee) based on the credentials entered.
Here's the basic structure of my code:

```
import data
username = input("Enter a username: ")
password = input("Enter a password: ")

def log_in(username, password):
    # login logic here...

 Rest of the code...
```

I am struggling with the following:

How do I effectively convert the txt file into a dictionary in the main function?
Once a user is authenticated, how can I transition to the appropriate menu based on their role?
Any assistance or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pls format your code properly. Also read: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: fixed, I was banned from asking, so I'm asking chatGPT to edit my previous questions to align with the guidelines, I gave him the guidelines and how to ask  links

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read the text file in, convert into CSV. See here
[Python csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv)

Comment: Thanks you , I solved the issue but I'm improving the questions to lift an automatic ban

Comment: This is pretty much a link-only answer. Please provide information from the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a txt file like this

```
James,$8000
Joe,$50000
Jill,$90000
```

And save with the name `text_file.txt`.
Now you can read the txt file with python and store the data in dictionary.

```
file  = "text_file.txt" # location of text file
details = {} #dictionary
with open(file, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        emp = line.strip().split(",")
        details[emp[0]] = emp[1]
print(details) #print the dictionary after reading
```

Comment: Note that `open(file_name)` opens it in `r` mode by default.

Comment: Noted. However we are not writing anything on txt file. We are just reading and storing it in dictionary

Comment: I am not saying anything about writing it to a text file. I'm saying `open(file)` is equivalent, and shorter than `open(file, 'r')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a security risk¹, you can save it in JSON format. Here is an example of it (formatted for readability):

```json
{
  "Banana": 3,
  "Random": 1
}
```

You can read it like this²:

```py
file_name = "file.txt" # Assign the file name to a variable for later use

with open(file_name) as f:
    data = eval(f.read())
```

You can also write to the file like this (assuming it's in the same format as the data that has been read)²:

```py
file_name = "file.txt" # Assign the file name to a variable for later use

with open(file_name, "w") as f:
    f.write(str(data))
```

---

###### ¹ The security risk comes from using `eval`, which can allow someone to execute arbitrary code.

###### ² It is possible to use the `json` Python library for this as well, using `json.dumps` for turning dictionaries into json strings, and `json.load` for turning json strings into dictionaries. This does not carry the security risk of `eval`.